# Sqoop Incremental append mode not importing null rows for --check-column, This columns is timestamp and has null value

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

I am trying to do incremental import initially using following command.

sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@orau20:1555:XXX --username XXXX --password XXXX --table emp   -fields-terminated-by '\001' --escaped-by '\' --input-null-string "\\N"  --input-null-non-string "\\N"  --target-dir /user/xxx/Test/emp --incremental append --check-column dttm_stamp_sec -m 1

Here i found some of the records are missing which dttm_stamp_sec is null records. This column has some null records and those records are not importing from oracle to hadoop. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We should specify the --check-column which always have a value init